# How are these 2 uses of `$this` different?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm studying up on some AngularJS code at the moment and I noticed two different uses of `$this` in the definition of an AngularJS factory:

```
module.factory('f_sys', function(...) {
  var $this = { data : { id: "123" } };

  ...

  function _updateSystem(d) {
    return $this.data.id == "123";  // (true)
  }

  $this.init = function() {
    ...
  }

  ...

  return $this;
});
```

What's happening here? Is the `init` function being added as another key to the `var $this` object? Is it treated just like another function (i.e. like `_updateSystem`)?

Comment: We can't really answer that without seeing a complete version of your code. Something is clearly happening to `$this` in the omitted parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`init` is not like the other function. It is like you say: it becomes a property of the `$this` object. So you can call `$this.init()`, but to call `_updateSystem` you cannot write `$this._updateSystem()`. And as you return `$this` to the caller, the caller *can* call `init()`, but not `_updateSystem()`.

The construction of `$this` is the same as if you would have written it in one single assignment:

```
var $this = { 
    data: { 
        id: "123" 
    }, 
    init: function() {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Or in a more modern (ES6) syntax:

```
const $this = { 
    data: { 
        id: "123" 
    }, 
    init() {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```